# opendaylight:karaf: how to overide dependency of the parent pom

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf, opendaylight

I am writing an ODL app where I want to use openstack4j. I am running into the following problem when I load the feature:

```
    Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement 
    [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=features-vlan; type=karaf.feature; 
    version="[0.1.0,0.1.0]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=features-vlan)
    (type=karaf.feature)(version>=0.1.0)(version<=0.1.0))" [caused by:
    Unable to resolve features-vlan/0.1.0: missing requirement [features-
    vlan/0.1.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-vlan; type=karaf.feature;
    version="[0.1.0,0.1.0]" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-vlan/0.1.0: 
    missing requirement [odl-vlan/0.1.0] osgi.identity; 
     osgi.identity=com.github.fge.jackson-coreutils; type=osgi.bundle; 
    version="[1.6.0,1.6.0]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to
    resolve com.github.fge.jackson-coreutils/1.6.0: missing requirement 
    [com.github.fge.jackson-coreutils/1.6.0] osgi.wiring.package; 
    filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)
    (version>=16.0.0)(!(version>=17.0.0)))"]]]
```

Apparently jackson-coreutils wants version 16.0.0 whereas the effective pom specifies version 22.

So I tried the following hack in my impl pom :

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <instructions>
                <Embed-Dependency>openstack4j;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>
                <!-- same as in bundles4-test/pom.xml: -->
                <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
              </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I was hoping that the dependency openstack4j would be added statically in the bundle but it did not work. How can I proceed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So jackson-coreutil depends on a much older version of guava than odlparent (22). Maybe there's a newer version of jackson-coreutil? If not then I think you need to install the older 16.x guava version to satisfy jackson-coreutil. Hopefully versions 16.x and 22 can co-exist peacefully in the same karaf container. If you embed the openstack4j dependency, then try also embedding guava 16.x or set Embed-Transitive to true assuming openstack4j pulls it in transitively.

Comment: Thanks. Tried the Embed-Transitive tag but it does not work. I will try out jclouds ( probably integrates easier).

Comment: Stuck there too! This time with gson.